# Simultaneous INSERT and UPDATE MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

What I'd like to say is something like:

Update a count by 1 if an id exists add it if not.

I have tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO links (id, count) VALUES (:id, 1)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

which is some PHP code, I can add the ids, but I can't increment the count. Any ideas please?

Comment: Is `id` defined to be a primary key or unique?

Comment: Your code should work fine if `id` is properly assigned as primary key.

Comment: I do not `mysql` has this functionality in oracle `merge into`, although mysql has `replace` syntax, it is not as good as `merge`

Comment: @Rugal `replace` performs a delete-then-reinsert, in this case the content needs to be updated so `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` is the correct functionality to use.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes   cool! thanks, I need this syntax!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql?rq=1